# How to change default prefix icon theme in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have had an issue. I change color of prefix icon in TextField  with colorScheme, but how to change default prefix icon color. I have tried to change it this way

```
data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
        iconTheme: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.copyWith(
            color: Colors.red,
        ),
        colorScheme: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.copyWith(
            primary: Colors.blue,
        ),
),
```

But this way doesn't work

Comment: @Nagual preffix Icon of TextField

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a fixed icon color you can use this:

```dart
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.done, color: Colors.green),
  ),
),
```

There's a issue on [Github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33183) about this

**Update:**

See this code

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  FocusNode _focus = FocusNode();

  //Define your default color  
  Color fieldColor = Colors.green;

  //Using focus node everytime the focus change the listener will change the 
  //color and call setState
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _focus.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        fieldColor = _focus.hasFocus ? Colors.red : Colors.black;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: TextField(
          focusNode: _focus,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.done, color: fieldColor),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: But when I do that, I can't control focus color

Answer (score 0):

I was able to change wrapping the `TextField`:

```
Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(primaryColor: Colors.black),
      child: TextFormField(),
    );
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, nothing change ![](https://i.imgur.com/5ERwhVW.png)